# Forecast equation in Holt’s linear trend method

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a question about the forecast equation in Holt’s linear trend method used to analyze time-series.

As the forecast equation is `prediction = l + hb` where `l` is the last value of the level equation, `b` the last value of the trend equation and `h` the time-horizon.

As long as `h` was 1 I had no problem but how do I do with `h = 5`? Do I multiply by 5 the last value of `b`? Do I take the average of the 5 previous values of `b`? Do I take the fifth last value of `b`?

Answer (score 1):

You multiply 5 by the last value of b.

Suppose your last value is 666, and b is 2.

Your forecast 1 period out is 668
Your forecast 2 periods out is 670
...
Your forecast 5 periods out is 676
and so on.